# Packages vs Stored Procedures in simple scenarios?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, package

I have an application that contains multiple inline queries. My plan is to make them into stored procedures, but after some research I found out that packages are the way to go, but that would just an extra layer to access the stored procedure. All of my queries are very simple, just `SELECT` statements and some a bit more "complex" with `CASE`. Is there really a benefit for me to put them into packages after I make them into stored procedures?

Comment: I personally prefer using both packages and storedproc's this depends on what you are comfortable with as well as are you the only one going to utilize the package? if so then why not use a stored procedure also in my opinion in regards to Oracle it's probably easier to recompile separate stored procs vs compiling a package and having one of the Stored procs fail / not compile then you have to look at all the stored procs within that package to see which one has failed vs knowing which one failed to compile if it were just a single stored proc.. this one is entirely opinionated and up to you

Comment: I would use a stand alone procedure only for the demos. Otherwise, in production environment, I don't find any reason to use stand alone procedures. I wrap them in packages based on the founctional aspects.

Comment: @lalitKumarB what would be the benefit of putting `SELECT * FROM users Where user_id = 34` inside a package?

Comment: @User456789 You must never do a `SELECT *` in a production database.

Comment: What would be the benefit of putting `SELECT * FROM users Where user_id = 34` inside a [subprogram](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/subprograms.htm#LNPLS008) ?

Comment: [Reasons to Use Packages](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/packages.htm#LNPLS009). If you found none of those reasons apply in your case then you don't have to use packages. (I'll use packages in 99% of the cases).

Comment: @LalitKumarB, there are good reasons to use SELECT * in a prod system; e.g. when you are selecting into a record type based on a %ROWTYPE.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp Hmm, it is one such reason,can't generalize it. Probably, you understood what I meant by saying *You must never do a SELECT * in a production database*. There are cases where it is OK to use it, however, it is better to avoid it. Don't you think it is better to explicitly mention the column names rather than a select *?

Comment: There's a difference between "it is better to explicitly list columns" vs. "you **must never**".

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not new. There have had been numerous debates/discussions regarding a stand alone procedure versus a package.

Thomas Kyte has beautifully answered in his site for a similar question, I would like to quote:

> because packages
>
> - break the dependency chain (no cascading invalidations when you install a new package body -- if 
>     you have procedures that call procedures -- compiling one will invalidate your database)
> - support encapsulation -- I will be allowed to write MODULAR, easy to understand code -- rather 
>     then MONOLITHIC, non-understandable procedures
> - increase my namespace measurably.  package names have to be unique in a schema, but I can have 
>     many procedures across packages with the same name without colliding
> - support overloading
> - support session variables when you need them
> - promote overall good coding techniques, stuff that lets you write code that is modular, 
>     understandable, logically grouped together.
>
> If you are a programmer - you would see the benefits of packages over a proliferation of standalone 
>   procedures in a heartbeat.

Read more about it here https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:7452431376537

The best out of it is:

> Always use a package.
>
> Never use a standalone procedure except for demos, tests and standalone utilities (that 
>   call nothing and are called by nothing)

Comment: my queries are really simple and there is really no benefits for me to use more than half of the options you listed.

Comment: Those are not listed by me, but agreed and implemented by majority of the database users. These are considered as best practices.

Answer (score 0):

If you have logic that can be handled as part of a SQL statement, then, in general, I would not recommend pulling them out and turning them into functions (which is, let's face it, what you'd be turning them into), regardless if they were standalone or inside a package.

The reason for this is when you have a user defined function call inside a sql statement, the sql statement has to break out of the sql engine, switch to the pl/sql engine and then back again... for every row. This will most likely slow down your query.

There are, of course, always exceptions - sometimes if you have a frequent function call that's returning the same value, it's possible to make use of function caching.

ETA: You say you have multiple inline queries - if they're all the same (or very similar), you could potentially use subquery factorying (aka the with clause aka common table expressions (CTE)) to materialize the results.